# Swift4: `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue()` returns `AXError.cannotComplete`

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, accessibility, swift4

On running the following code:

```
let pid = getAppPid()
let AXApp = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid)

var children: CFTypeRef?
let returnVal = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(AXApp,
    kAXChildrenAttribute as CFString, &children)
```

- `AXApp` gets created successfully

However

- `children` is `nil`
- `returnVal` is [`AXError.cannotComplete`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/axerror/1460335-cannotcomplete) (*"A fundamental error has occurred, such as a failure to allocate memory during processing."*)

I've seen code on stack overflow and elsewhere using exactly the same method as I am.

What am I missing.

I am using Xcode 9/Swift 4 on MacOS High Sierra.

EDIT:

I should add that Xcode has accessibility permissions, and I am able to successfully do other stuff that requires accessibility permission like `CGEvent.tapCreate()` to monitor global keyboard events etc.

Comment: Switch off sandboxing. [How to use Accessibility with sandboxed app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116095/how-to-use-accessibility-with-sandboxed-app)

Comment: Thanks, that works. If you add that as answer, I'll mark it as the right one.

Comment: Also: I was able to get it working by setting the `App Sandbox` key to `NO` in the `.entitlements` file. I this the best way? I couldn't find a key to just request entitlement for accessibility, while preserving the rest of the sandbox compliance features. Do you know if some thing like that exists? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about App Sandbox. I managed to switch it off but that's it.

Comment: cool, I am doing the same. do you want to put your initial comment as an answer?